# Blank Space in Python\KivyMd custom MDDialog

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

at first i am new to stackoverflow and python\kivy development, hope that i do everything right here :D.

**Background:**
i tried to create a simple reusable DialogSelector with python\kivymd where i can throw some items in and get a popup with the items to select.

Everything works just fine as intended, but i get a blank space above the ScrollView and i don´t know where this comes from.

[Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsgCo.png)

Im sure there are better ways to do this but thats what i came up with (DialogSelector.py):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton


Builder.load_string( """
<CustomDLG>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "200dp"
    pos_hint: { "top": 1 }

    ScrollView:
        id: scView
        
        MDList:
            id: itemList
""" )


class CustomDLG( BoxLayout ):
    pass


class DialogSelector():

    def __init__( self, title, items, callback ):
        self.items = items
        self.title = title
        self.callback = callback
        self.dialog = None
        self.displayed = None
        self.keyword = None

    def open(self, *args):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title=self.title,
                type="custom",
                size_hint=(.8, .7),
                content_cls=CustomDLG(),
                buttons=[ MDFlatButton( text="Abbrechen",  on_release=self.close ) ]
            )

        self.dialog.content_cls.ids.itemList.clear_widgets()
        for entry in self.items:
            if type(entry) is str: entry = { "Keyword": entry, "Displayed": entry }
            if type(entry) is dict:
                if "Keyword" in entry and "Displayed" in entry:
                    self.dialog.content_cls.ids.itemList.add_widget( 
                        OneLineListItem( id=str(entry["Keyword"]), text=str(entry["Displayed"]), on_release=self.itemSelected ) 
                    )

        self.dialog.open()


    def close(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss( force=True )


    def itemSelected(self, item):
        self.displayed = item.text
        self.keyword = item.id
        if self.dialog: self.dialog.dismiss( force=True )
        self.callback( self )
```

Usage (some other .py):

```
from CustomWidgets.DialogSelector import DialogSelector

    def openCategoryDialog(self):
        self.dialog = DialogSelector( 
            title = "Kategorie wählen", 
            items = [{"Keyword":"A", "Displayed":"ABCDE"},{"Keyword":"B", "Displayed":"BEDF"}], 
            callback = self.categorySelected 
            )
        self.dialog.open()

    def categorySelected(self, dlg):
        print( dlg.keyword )
        print( dlg.displayed )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just found out its much easier.
If i use the OneLineAvatarIconListItem it works with a confirmation dialog.
That works for me, still it would be better with just OneLineListItem but this causes an error.

```
    def openCategoryDialog(self):
        self.dialog = MDDialog( 
            title="Kategorie wählen",
            type="confirmation",
            size_hint = (.8, .7),
            items=[
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="A01", text="Callisto", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="B02", text="Luna", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="C03", text="Night", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="D04", text="Solo", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="E05", text="Phobos", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="F06", text="Diamond", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="G07", text="Sirena", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="H08", text="Red music", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="I09", text="Allergio", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="J10", text="Magic", on_release=self.categorySelected),
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(id="K11", text="Tic-tac", on_release=self.categorySelected)
            ],
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton( text="Abbrechen", on_release=self.closeCategoryDialog ),
            ]
        )
        self.dialog.open()

    def closeCategoryDialog(self, *args):
        self.dialog.dismiss( force=True )

    def categorySelected(self, dlg):
        print( dlg.id )
        print( dlg.text )
        self.dialog.dismiss( force=True )
```